# Escrever lista em arquivo binário

Tags: c, ponteiro, lista, lista-encadeada

A ideia desse método, é escrever todas as palavras de uma lista de nodos em um arquivo binário. Eu tenho uma lista ligada de nodos, onde cada nodo tem duas informações, a sua informação, e uma referencia para o próximo nodo da lista. A ideia é escrever a informação de cada nodo em um arquivo binario.
Porém, estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

**warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning
      to 'char' from 'const char *'**

Que ocorre nesta linha do código:

```
*pal = nodo->info;
```

Só não entendi qual o problema, já que a minha estrutura define a informação do nodo como um ponteiro também.
Segue abaixo o código da estrutura do NODO e o método

```
typedef struct Temp{
    char const *info;
    struct Temp *prox;
}TNODOPAL;
```

Método :

```
void escreveBinario(){

    TNODOPAL *nodo = inicioPal;

    FILE *fp;
    char *pal = NULL;

    fp = fopen( "binary.dat" , "wb" );

    if (fp == NULL) // Se não conseguiu criar
    {
        printf("Problemas na CRIACAO do arquivo\n");
        return;
    }

    while(nodo != NULL){
        *pal = nodo->info;
        fwrite (&pal, sizeof(char) * 30, 200, fp);
        nodo = nodo->prox;
    }
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pal` é um ponteiro para char então `*pal` vai ser uma posição de memória contendo um `char`. Quando `você faz`*pal = c`você está armazenando um char na posição de memória apontada pelo ponteiro`pal`.

Acho que o que você queria fazer é

```
pal = nodo->info
fwrite (pal, sizeof(char) * 30, 200, fp);
```

Ou simplesmente

```
fwrite (nodo->info, sizeof(char) * 30, 200, fp);
```

Comment: Só reparei agora que o arquivo criado está em branco. Sabe qual pode ser o possivel problema?